# Dart unittest filtering

Tags: testing, dart

I have a written a set of unittest for one of my Dart libraries, However I would like to be able to filter those to allow only certain ones to run during my continuous builds. I noticed that the unittest api allows for this to done but i can not find any examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter what tests are run by creating a custom configuration and using `filterTests()`.

```dart
import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";

class FilterTests extends Configuration {
  get autoStart => false; // this ensures that the tests won't just run automatically
}

void useFilteredTests() {
  configure(new FilterTests()); // tell configure to use our custom configuration
  ensureInitialized(); // needed to get the plumbing to work
}
```

Then, in `main()`, you use `useFilterTests()` and then call `filterTests()` with string or a regexp for the tests you want to run.

```dart
void main() {
  useFilteredTests();

  // your tests go here

  filterTests(some_string_or_regexp);
  runTests();
}
```

Tests whose description matches the argument to `filterTests()` will run; other tests will not. I wrote a [blog post](http://shailen.github.com/blog/2012/12/07/running-only-some-of-your-tests/) on using `filterTests()` that you might find useful.

Another approach to filtering tests if to divide them into multiple libraries and then `import()` the `main()` function of only those libraries whose tests you want to run.
So, imagine one library containing some tests:

```dart
library foo_tests;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";

void main() {
  // some tests for foo()
}
```

and another one containing other tests:

```dart
library bar_tests;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";

void main() {
  // some tests for bar()
}
```

You can sew together a test-runner by importing `main()` from each of these libraries. In, `my_tests.dart`, you could do this to run all your tests:

```dart
import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "foo_tests.dart" as foo_tests;
import "bar_tests.dart" as bar_tests;

void main() {
  foo_tests.main();
  bar_tests.main();
}
```

If you wanted to run only `foo_tests` or only `bar_tests`, you could just import one. This would effectively create a filter.  Here is a [simple working example](https://github.com/shailen/droneDemo/tree/master/test) of how these imports work